# Handling error in CronJob executing function

Tags: node.js, error-handling, callback, cron-task

I am using [CronJob](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron). What should I do if I get an error when executing **myFunction**

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 30 11 * * 1-5', function myFunction() {
     //Do something
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true, /* Start the job right now */
  timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```

Comment: It depends.  What kind of error?

Comment: Error when querying database as an example

Answer (score 0):

Just put if/else statement for error. That way your app won't crash. You can add a logger to your app and log all errors that occur in cron job.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 30 11 * * 1-5', function myFunction() {
  User.findOne({_id: user_id}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    } else {
       //success
       console.log(results);
    }
  })
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true, /* Start the job right now */
  timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```